# What is the origin of the phrase "up the guts"

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions, new-zealand-english

'Up the guts' is a colloquial phrase used in New Zealand and Australia generally to refer to a direct (both literal and figurative) approach to something.

It is somewhat vulgar, but not generally considered offensive.

It is used in everyday language, but is particularly common in Rugby and sporting lexicon, in which it means to run or play the ball straight (generally through the opposition rather than around them), covering the shortest distance possible in order to score a point.

For example:

Person A: "What's the play?"

Person B: "Nothing fancy. Straight up the guts."

It has been claimed by some to have misogynistic origins, however  I can't find any proof or explanation of this.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can't find anything much to indicate an origin. It seems like a reference to gutting a fish/animal, where you need to get up inside and pull out the viscera; it seems to relate to a direct move up the middle which could match either a gutting cut, or an upward blow with a weapon.  Worth noting that "courage" is a well-established secondary meaning of "guts" as in the idiom "get up the guts"/"work up the guts" meaning to pluck up courage to do something. "as rough as guts" is apparently Aus/NZ slang for uncultured or unsophisticated, so they like their offal.

Comment: It's something like "get straight to the heart/meat of the matter"